# a org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: node is used in a different document than the one that created it

Tags: java, xml, dom

I am getting the error
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR: A node is used in a different document than the one that created it.
This is a line inside a servlet and the message.  I don't see how, as I simply am inserting a single item
into an empty tree.  The problem, right now appears to be intermittant.

```
     DocumentBuilderFactory Factory;
    Factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {
        parser = Factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        log.fine("cannot create new parser");
    }
    d = parser.newDocument();
    root = d.createElement("DT");
    d.insertBefore(root, null);
```

When other people discussed this error message, there was in issue of imporitng nodes.

Answer (score 0):

```
d.insertBefore(root, null);
```

the second argument `refChild` cannot be null; instead you can do:

```
d.appendChild(root);
```